# I am redirected to a router that is not part of my provider's configuration

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, linux-mint

Whenever I try to access a website with a .com domain it shows the 'unable to connect page' but when I access a site with my country's domain I get redirected to a Tenda 11N wireless router.

I called my ISP and the network guy said they do not use that router and he doesn't know why it redirects me to that router's login page. He also tried to connect his windows laptop and saw the page. I have a wired connection to go through so why it would show me a wireless router's login page is beyond me.

Sometimes the connection works but I get disconnected and the same behavior repeats. Could it be that someone is blocking me through that router /stealing my connection somehow ?

I am a noob at networks please help, I can update command outputs if necessary.

**Update**
Whenever I look at my pc's network settings the wireless hotspot is always on, even after I disable it. Don't know if it's related or not.

Comment: Could you include the output of an external ping?

Comment: Pinging https://www.facebook.com i get unknown host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your wired connection is intercepted somewhere between your computer and the ISP entry-point into the house. This Tenda router is in between somewhere and it shouldn't be.
So follow the wires and remove it.
That is so obvious that I'm very surprised the ISP tech didn't do this himself.

Cousin of mine had a similar problem a few years ago. Previous owner of the building had done the wiring and had placed his own router hidden beneath the floor, forgot to remove it when he left. My cousin thought he had a straight connection to the ISP box on the floor, while in reality it went through this other router.
My cousin initially didn't notice, until the ISP replaced the ISP router-box and he couldn't get his computer to connect to it.

PS
You don't mention this, but if the ISP connection is shared among multiple customers in the building, the Tenda router may belong to someone else in the building. If that is the case that guy has mis-configured/mis-wired the Tenda router.

Comment: The connection is shared in the building, I'll come back with an answer to see if there is an extra cable plugged in somewhere, or maybe the person is just trying to connect 2 devices on his wireless router and when a second device connects I get disconnected? Is that also a possibility?

Comment: @user2988146 Could be. Most likely.

Comment: yeah, so I changed the password of the wireless network of the router a couple of times and also the name of the network, and that seemed to make the person realize he/she was doing something wrong, so it works now, good thing for the default admin/admin user/password

Comment: @User2988146 NIce job :-) And don't call yourself a noob :-) You're already way ahead of most "noob" users !